# Getting test run Category during runtime. In VSTest task it's called TestFilterCriteria

Tags: c#, azure-pipelines

I am looking for getting the Category runtime to get as an environment variable or something.

Comment: Could you explain this issue a little more please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Getting test run Category during runtime. In VSTest task it's called TestFilterCriteria

I am afraid you could not get current category in the test method code directly at runtime.

As workaround, you can read the value from RunSettings file (`TestContext.Properties[xxx]`) and override the parameter during the test by following steps:

- Define a variable to store category
- Specify filters with that variable in Test Filter criteria input box
  of Visual Studio test task
- Specify parameters in Override TestRun Parameters input box of Visual
  Studio Test task

Check the blog [Supplying Run Time Parameters to Tests](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/09/04/supplying-run-time-parameters-to-tests/) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's what I did as well. However it is disappointing that I cannot get the Category for the current test. :(